# Standard error of the sample mean

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation

Suppose I have a data set of $N>100$ samples. Knowing the sample mean $\bar x$ and the sample standard deviation $S$. How may I compute the sample mean confidence interval with a 95% confidence level?

My problem is that I have not information about the population distribution and its standard deviation.

Comment: I need to compute the confidence interval for a sample mean. With a 95% confidence level. I have the sample data, so I can get all the information from them.

Comment: I do not know their distribution. BTW I got the standard deviation, mean, mode, median,... and all the statistical descrittive parameters.

Comment: I cannot answer your question if you don´t give us all the information you have. The answer depends on the given information. I think I have to give up.

Comment: I reformulated my question, with all the information I have.

Comment: In general you can use the central limit theorem, I think.  Do you have N samples with a sample size of n or one sample with a sample size of N ? And are the samples independent ?

Comment: I have one sample with a sample size of N. The data are independent. Use the central limit theorem means to suppose the sample be normal distributed, right? However I cannot figure the procedure out, operatively speaking.

Comment: Yes. You have to know the singles values of your sample to estimate the variance. Or if you want to calculate the confidence interval of the proportion the variance of the sample proportion is $\frac{p\cdot (1-p)}{N}$

Comment: I have the values of the sample, and I already computed the sample variance. I need to compute the sample mean confidence level, so all the possible values of the sample mean which are let me say realistic. I do not know what the confidence interval of the proportion is. What does the p in your formula represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following statistical formula,
$$\bar{x}\pm\frac{ts}{\sqrt{n}}$$
where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, $s$ is your standard deviation, $n$ is the sample size, and $t$ is the critical value you can obtain from a $t$-table under 95% confidence. Here is a link to one with the 95% confidence bands highlighted https://www2.palomar.edu/users/rmorrissette/Lectures/Stats/ttests/TTable.jpg.

As an aside, a theoretical construct can be derived from probability theory. From Chebyshev's inequality (the inside rather than outside interval version):
$$\Pr\left(|X-\mu|\leq k\sigma\right)\geq\frac{1}{k^2}$$
Here we have population mean $\mu$, population standard deviation $\sigma$, and random variable $X$.To find $k$ on the 95% confidence interval, solve $1/k^2=1-0.95$ to obtain $k=2\sqrt{5}$. The confidence interval is the inequality within the parentheses. Rearranging it becomes,
$$\mu-k\sigma\leq X\leq \mu+k\sigma$$
This is just an aside. Use the first equation (statistical) for your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Dante You can use the central limit theorem. But it look it looks like that you don´t want.

Comment: @Cocomos presented exactly what I need. Nevertheless I am open Band interested to other solutions, if you can explain me it, you will be welcome!

Comment: @Dante If it is exacly what you need the there is no need that I post another answer.

Comment: It could be interesting.